# Delay before repeating a CAAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, caanimation

hi have a simple core animation :

```
NSString *keyPath2 = @"anchorPoint.y";
CAKeyframeAnimation *kfa2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath2];
[kfa2 setValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-.05],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.1],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-.1],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.1],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-.05],
                 nil]];
//[kfa2 setRepeatCount:10];
[kfa2 setRepeatDuration:30];
[kfa2 setDuration:.35];
[kfa2 setAdditive:YES];
[kfa2 setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

How can i set a delay before the animation get repeated ?

And if someone can explain if the difference between repeatCount and repeatDuration.

I do not want to use a @selector.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

According to [CAMediaTiming protocol's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/CAMediaTiming/repeatCount), `repeatCount` and `repeatDuration` should *not* be set simultaneously, `repeatCount` means what it means, `repeatDuration` is just another way to set `repeatCount`, ie `repeatCount` = `repeatDuration / duration`.

You can simulate a delay with `CAKeyframeAnimation` by adding an additional last value. For example you have the following animation

```
kfa.values = @[@1, @3, @7]; // Using object literal syntax (Google it!), the way to go
kfa.keyTimes = @[@.0, @.5, @1]; // 0.5 = 5 / 10; 1 = 10 / 10;
kfa.duration = 10; // 10 sec, for demonstration purpose
```

And now you want it to delay 1 sec before it repeats. Simply change the thing to:

```
kfa.values = @[@1, @3, @7, @7]; // An additional value
kfa.keyTimes = @[@.0, @.4546, @.9091, @1]; // 0.4546 = 5 / 11; 0.9091 = 10 / 11; 1 = 11 / 11
kfa.duration = 11;
```

The calculation is a bit messy, but fairly straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use CAAnimationGroup.

```
let scale         = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale") // or CAKeyFrameAnimation
scale.toValue = 2.0
scale.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
scale.duration    = 0.4
scale.beginTime   = 1.0 // Repeat delay.
let scaleGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
scaleGroup.duration    = scale.duration + scale.beginTime
scaleGroup.fillMode    = kCAFillModeForwards
scaleGroup.repeatCount = Float.infinity
scaleGroup.animations  = [scale]
scaleGroup.beginTime   = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.8 // Initial delay.

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

let viewb = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
viewb.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.addSubview(viewb)

viewb.layer.add(scaleGroup, forKey: "")

// If you want to try this on Playground
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: scale.beginTime represents delay only before first loop, but not before each animation loop.

Comment: @eXhausted Can you try sample code once more?
I modified the sample code and tried it on Xcode8.2.1 Playground, I could confirm scale.beginTime applied to each animation loop.